# How can I load this ASP.NET div after the page has been loaded?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

There is a div on my page currently that makes a lot of requests to the server, so the pages takes about 10 seconds to load. We don't always need this data, so I want to be able to have the page load with all of the info except for this one div. Once the page is loaded 100% I want it to load this div (maybe show a loading...).

I've made an ajax request from my TrackingData.aspx as a test, but I can't seem to get this to work.

My JavaScript

```
 function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TrackingData.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert("bye");
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

And the HTML

```
Your Name :
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
    onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
</div>
```

The C# code is simply

```
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

There is a TrackingData.aspx in the same folder, and it has a method GetCurrentTime. This is just a test method, but I should be able to do the rest on my own once I get this working.

Comment: You said your request is to default.aspx?

Comment: Did you add '[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]' before method?

Comment: What do you mean "Can't get this to work"? You need to be clear. Is your code reached? How far does it get? Do you get any error messages? Any errors in your JavaScript console or on the server's event logs? Please include these details in your question, and realize you need to anticipate these questions and include this information in the future.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Sorry, it was. I changed it. I'll fix my wording.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi I did not. I'll try that.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Wow that actually was all I needed...

If you want to make an answer Farzin, I will select is as correct.

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this before your static method (GetCurrentTime):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
```

And to avoid some faults you can use json stringify for your data:

```
data: { name: JSON.stringify($("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value)}
```